# Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type - AWS amplify with React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to create data on Appsync with react native by using

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createBotdata, {input: dataEntry}))
```

But I get this **error**:
`error creating dataEntry: {"data": null, "errors": [{"locations": [Array], "message": "Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type CreateBotdataInput", "path": null}, {"locations": [Array], "message": "Validation error of type UnknownType: Unknown type ModelBotdataConditionInput", "path": null}, {"locations": [Array], "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'createBotdata' in type 'Mutation' is undefined @ 'createBotdata'", "path": null}]}`

I can confirm that I have it all, `CreateBotdataInput`, `ModelBotdataConditionInput` and `createBotdata` at mutation.js
[mutation.js-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nt7h.png)

I also can confirm that variable type are alinged as well.
[schema.graphql-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN6jz.png)

```
dataENtry:  {"client_id": "yo7634", "id": "yo7634", "lock_status": 3, "timestamp": ""}
```

Finally, I do import mutations.js on the file as well.

```
import { createBotdata } from '../src/graphql/mutations'
```

This bug is dirving me crazy so I'll be greatful if I can get a pointer to fix it

Comment: I have the feeling that your problem is related to async ops. I do not use await but is there a call back that could be called just after the await truly ends?

Comment: Shall I install async-ops as well?

Comment: I am talking from my experience working with async operations using react and Axios. My intuition tells me that if your API.graphql() or what is inside it (graphqllOperation) is async by nature then you might need to use async commands (maybe included in that async-ops library you mentioned). For Axios I had to use the call backs that were triggered only after the respective Axios request was complete.

Comment: I found something that might help you:
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/